# What are some unusual languages you have used for a CGI application?

Tags: language-agnostic, cgi

I'm sure we (I'm referring to web developers) have at one time or another used a web scripting language like php, perl, python, or asp.

But, we know you can also write cgi applications in languages like C.

So, has anyone used an unusual language for writting CGI applications? By unusual, I mean a language that is not generally known for writing CGI apps with. Please make sure your answers are about languages you have actually used to write CGI apps - although bizzare languages may be mentioned for humorous effect.

Edit - to make this more educational, please include links to the languages you reference. - unless it's a common language, like pascal.

Comment: I don't see why this belongs on -1, so +1 back to 0.

Comment: Because CW is usually just an attempt to get rep.

Comment: ??? You don't get rep from community wiki...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG), running off Apache on a AS/400.

Comment: weird, but I bet you had zero downtime :)

Comment: For those who don't know what RPG is, I added a link.

Comment: Only because you didn't have APL, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what APL is.

Comment: APL is the only language I could think of that's less likely to be used for CGI than RPG.  Here's some APL code for you: x[⍋x←6?40].  APL has been described as a "write-only language."

Comment: That;s uber geeky...what columns did you have to use for the RPG code - any code available?

Comment: That's "standard" RPG code, but it uses the CGIDEV2 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgidev2) dev toolkit to process query strings and produce HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

[Matlab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB).  Which is pretty strange.  [Emacs Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp), which is perhaps stranger.  But I think the best strange one was a dashboard for an embedded gadget written in [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash).

Answer (score 1):

What no one has used x86 assembly for their CGI?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote one in Ada once, but **I** don't consider Ada to be all that unusual.

As a matter of fact, Ada by default is immune to many of the standard buffer overflow exploits, so it is a pretty good choice of language if you want your CGI "script" to be secure.

Comment: Buffer overflows aren't the only concern :)

Answer (score 1):

I routinely use [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/), and like it.

The strangest I have used is probably [Ansi M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS).

Answer (score 1):

I created the lightweight [CMS system MiniMagAsm](http://asm32.hopto.org/index.cgi?page=content/0_MiniMagAsm/index.txt) in assembly language.

It is portable among x86 based servers and works on Windows and Linux (32 and 64 bit) pretty well. The project is free.

The system is created using [Fresh](http://fresh.flatassembler.net) with FreshLib library. (both are my projects as well).